# woff2 file can't be accessed on apache webserver

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, woff2

I'm trying to reach (download or load) a woff2 file on an apache server using hestiacp and I have a 500 error.

In the same folder if I put a ttf file when I reach it it downloads it normally.
I tried to manage it with a .htaccess file adding

```
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
```

and then even restarting apache it won't work.

I also tried adding this type on my apache configuration file.

Comment: _"and I have a 500 error"_ - and what does the error log have to say about that?

Comment: `[Thu Jul 28 08:22:22.478506 2022] [negotiation:error] [pid 471] [client ***.***.**.***:0] AH00681: Syntax error in type map, no ':' in /home/admin/web/*.com/public_html/font/Inter-roman.var.woff2 for header wof2`

Comment: for some reason mod_negotiation cause a problem because on '.var' on the filename. If I remove this part it's solved but I wanted to understand why...

Comment: That's because default configuration for that usually includes `AddHandler type-map .var`, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation And when you check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype, there it says, _"Filenames may have multiple extensions and the extension argument will be compared against each of them."_

Comment: Is it possible to consider only the second extension?

Comment: No, the last part of what I quoted is pretty clear about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> AH00681: Syntax error in type map, no ':' in /home/admin/web/*.com/public_html/font/Inter-roman.var.woff2 for header wof2

The server thinks your woff2 file was actually a type map - but since it doesn't find any `:` in there, it doesn't consider it to be a *valid* type map file.

The reason / connection to content negotiation, is that the default configuration for that typically includes

```
AddHandler type-map .var
```

(https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation)

And as https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype says,

> Filenames may have multiple extensions and the extension argument will be compared against each of them.

This behavior is not configurable as far as I know, this is hard-coded functionality.

Comment: Let me add that you can easily override this in an .htaccess file per `RemoveHandler .var`